# Which of the two metrics DIT (Depth of Inheritance) or NOC (Number of Children) would be more problematic?

Tags: java, oop, metrics

Which of the two metrics DIT (Depth of Inheritance) or NOC (Number of Children) would be more problematic? Let's assume that a DIT of 15 and an NOC of 15 is there,which is more problematic and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with a high depth of inheritance is that you create high dependencies between classes of that hierarchy. Let's say you have a class hierarchy with `Class A` as parent, `Class B` extends `Class A`, `Class C` extends `Class B` and so on. `Class B` has a high dependency to `Class A`. But `Class C` has a high dependency to both `Class A` and `Class B`. Therefore, you increase coupling with each children in the hierarchy.

Having high number of children may not be as bad because you only generate dependencies between the parent and each children.

One of the main mantras of object design is high cohesion and loose coupling.

Comment: That is a very clear explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According Chidamber and Kemerer at ["Towards a metric suite for object-oriented design"](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/49292/towardsmetricssu00chid.pdf?s..) depth is preferred to breadth in the hierarchy. The paper ["Metrics for maintainability of class inheritance hierarchies"](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/49292/towardsmetricssu00chid.pdf?s..) is a good read. Reading the first reference, the authors argue that depth promotes reuse of methods through inheritance.

Comment: Both links are the same.

Comment: The correct link for the second reference: ["Metrics for maintainability of class inheritance hierarchies"](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~sheldon/public/Sheldon-smr249.pdf)